# Bounded away from 0 almost surely

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, random-variables

Suppose that for a succession of random variables $X_n \to 1$ almost surely.

Does it hold that $P[X_n\geq 1/2]=1$ for $n$ large enough?

Comment: Why should we expect anything more than $P[X_n \ge 1/2]$ tending to $1$ as $n$ grows?  I don't see proving that it reaches $1$ for any finite $n$.

Comment: 24 minutes. Is this an indication of the value you put in your own question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, in general that's not true. Consider for example the random variables $$X_n(x) := 1-x^n \qquad (x \in [0,1])$$ defined on the probability space $([0,1],\mathcal{B}([0,1]),\lambda|_{[0,1]})$ where $\lambda$ denotes the Lebesgue measure. Then $X_n \to 1$ almost surely, but $X_n(x) < \frac{1}{2}$ for all $x \in \left[\left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^{\frac{1}{n}},1\right]$.